# Building APK through command line

Tags: android, command-line, sdk, apk

For a new Android Studio Project I have somehow generated the files that are generated  whenever we create a new project through Android Studio through a python script. This script also places the java and layout xml files in their respective locations. **Now I want to build this project and generate the APK through command line only (without opening Android Studio).**
I found the **[android](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html)** command but that command is deprecated and no longer supported.

[Image of the message when using android command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCBVn.png)

Now, can anyone please suggest any other way to build and create APK through command line?
I found this **[ant](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)** software but am unable to use it as I don't know how to create the build.xml file.
**Please help me out.**

Comment: gradlew.bat :app:build

Comment: Please use search engine: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Comment: I'm a complete rookie in this stuff. Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.